# Error while installing gatsby.js starter templates

Tags: node.js, npm, gatsby

I want to make web app using `gatsby.js`
I have installed `gatsby-cli` globally using npm install.
But whenever I run `gatsby new gatsby-starter-forty https://github.com/codebushi/gatsby-starter-forty` or any other starter template command. I always end up with following error in my terminal

```
C:\Users\Sachin Verma\Desktop\gatsby>gatsby new gatsby-starter-forty https://github.com/codebushi/gatsby-starter-forty
info Creating new site from git: https://github.com/codebushi/gatsby-starter-forty.git
Cloning into 'gatsby-starter-forty'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 88, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (88/88), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (83/83), done.
Uremote: Total 88 (delta 7), reused 72 (delta 4), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (88/88), done.
[32msuccess[39m Created starter directory layout
[34minfo[39m Installing packages...
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...n"},"engines":{"node"'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Sachin Verma\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-10T15_43_11_180Z-debug.log

 ERROR

Command failed with exit code 1: npm install



  Error: Command failed with exit code 1: npm install

  - error.js:56 makeError
    [npm]/[gatsby-cli]/[execa]/lib/error.js:56:11

  - index.js:114 handlePromise
    [npm]/[gatsby-cli]/[execa]/index.js:114:26

  - task_queues.js:97 processTicksAndRejections
    internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5
```

Please suggest some way to fix it. As I am new to Node.js and can't fully understand the error

Answer (score 2):

Judging by your console output, I can see that you're using Windows. You will need some additional setup in order to get a working environment.

Take a look at the [official Gatsby on Windows docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-on-windows/).

In a nutshell, Gatsby recommends installing the `windows-build-tools` package to run on Windows:

> The recommended way to setup your build environment on Windows is to install the `windows-build-tools` package by running `npm install --global windows-build-tools --vs2015`

If this doesn't work for you, there is further information (including troubleshooting) in the [official Gatsby on Windows docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-on-windows/).

Alternatively, if you're on Windows 10, a good solution is to use Gatsby in the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL). To set it up, follow the instructions on the [WSL Linux](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-on-linux/#windows-subsystem-linux-wsl) docs.